# How to write a function that checks that one number is a power of another in Java?

Tags: java, function, numbers

I write a boolean function that checks if integer `m` is a power of `n` or not. But my code is not correct. For example, 625 is a power of 5. But my code returns false.

```java
public static boolean isPower(int m, int n) {
  if (m <= n) {
    return false;
  }
  int pow = n;
  while (pow <= m) {
    pow = n * pow;
    if (pow == m) {
      return true;
    }
    pow++;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `pow++` is the problem, its not needed at all

Comment: BTW `<=` can better be replaced by `<` (5 is a power of 5)

Comment: BTW no need to declare new scanner every time you read an input, 1 is more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

- A mistake of your solution was pointed out in the comments.
- Your code also doesn't handle the case of `m = 1` well.
- For the majority of inputs the following approach works in less iterations:

```java
// for n, m > 0
static boolean isPower(int m, int n) {
    while (m % n == 0) {
        m /= n;
    }
    
    return (m == 1);
}
```

Here I repeatedly divide `m` by `n` until a non-zero remainder is encountered. For an exact power of `n`, I will end up with `m = 1`.

`(n - 1)/n` of all possible `m` values with this approach are rejected on the first iteration since only one number in `n` consecutive numbers has `m % n == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers addressed the problem in the original code.  I thought I would show a method that doesn't use loops:

```
    public static boolean isPower (int base, int power) {
        double exponent =  Math.log (power) / Math.log (base) ;
        return (int) exponent == exponent;
    }
```

However, this doesn't address the issue of lack of precision when using `double`. For example, `base = 7` and `power = 16807` could result in `exponent = 5.000000000000001`. That would result in the method returning `false` when, in fact, it should be `true`. If you are not familiar with this issue, you should look into it. I'll leave the choice of fix to you.

Note: `log (a)` returns the natural logarithm of `a`. `log (a) / log (b)` converts the result to base `b`.

Answer (score 0):

@Shadov already answered your question, however there are some issues with your code I'd like to highlight. And example code below how to solve them.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("base: ");
    int base = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("result: ");
    int result = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(logarithm(base, result));
}
```

You don't have to create separate Scanner objects to collect multiple inputs. I removed my incorrect advice to close the Scanner. Don't do this for Scanner objects reading System.in because System.in will be permanently closed as well. In general, don't close resources you didn't create in your own code. Thanks Alexy for pointing this out in the comments.

The variable names `m` and `n` are a bit uninformative so I renamed them to `result` and `base` respectively. Also I changed the order in which they are entered.

```
public static Power logarithm(int base, int result) {
    int exponent = 0;
    int currentResult = 1;
    while (currentResult <= result) {
        if (currentResult == result) {
            return new Power(base, result, exponent);
        }
        currentResult = base * currentResult;
        exponent++;
    }
    return new Power(base, result);
}
```

The method you called `pow` is in effect performing a logarithm function:

2<sup>3</sup> = 8 -> log<sub>2</sub> 8 = 3

Provided with the base and the result, the function determines the exponent or power.

Your code returns false when the result is `1` or equal to the base. This is incorrect, for example:

log<sub>2</sub> 2 = 1

log<sub>2</sub> 1 = 0

Therefore I removed the `if (m <= n)` statement and changed the starting value of your `pow` (my `currentResult`) variable to 1.

Previously you just returned `true` or `false` but it would also make sense to return the exponent in the case that it is an integer. To do this I keep track of the exponent, and start it at `0`.

To distinguish success and failure cases I introduced a record called `Power`.

```
public record Power(int base, int result, Integer exponent) {
    public Power(int base, int result) {
        this(base, result, null);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (exponent == null) {
            return "%s is not a power of %s".formatted(result, base);
        } else {
            return "%s ^ %s = %s".formatted(base, exponent, result);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two constructors. One for the case that an exponent was found, and one for the case it wasn't. BTW this is the first time I ever used a Java record, yay!

Comment: Do not close a `Scanner` attached to `System.in`! Closing a `Scanner` closes the underlying stream; you don't want `System.in` get closed. Therefore do not use `Scanner(System.in)` with `try-with-resources`.

Comment: Really! I am checking this and will change my answer if it's true (probably). I didn't know this man.

Comment: More concisely, to prevent inadvertently closing the _[standard-input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)_ resource, close the _Scanner_ object after all input has been collected, for the cycle of the application.  Otherwise, you must close all objects that implement the _[Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html)_ interface.

Comment: _"... The variable names `m` and `n` are a bit uninformative ..."_, I disagree, they are two _[dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension)_.

Comment: @Reilas How are two parameters for a method dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I write a boolean function to recognize integer m as the power of n or not. But my code don not run properly. ..."*

Remove the incrementation of, *pow*.

Here is the *Wikipedia* article, on *[exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)*.

```java
boolean power(int m, int n) {
    if (m <= n) {
        return false;
    }
    int pow = n;
    while (pow <= m) {
        pow = n * pow;
        if (pow == m) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

> *"... For example, 625 is the power of 5. But my code result is false."*

Output

```
true
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
/* Returns true if y is a power of x */
public static boolean isPower(int x, int y)
{
    // The only power of 1 is 1 itself
    if (x == 1)
        return (y == 1);

    // Repeatedly compute power of x
    int pow = 1;
    while (pow < y)
        pow = pow * x;

    // Check if power of x becomes y
    return (pow == y);
}
```

Comment: You should explain how this fixes OP's problem, not to mention it won't work out of the box - `x` and `y` have exchanged positions compared to `m` and `n` used in question.

Comment: she can use this method, just passing correct params

Comment: Yes, and it should be explained in the answer. It should also explain where was the error in the question and how this fixes it.

Comment: Actually, any number in the power of zero is one, so you should just drop your `if` check. (There is a debate of whether 0^0 = 1, but for many purposes it's considered so.)